# Send and Receive bluetooth data at the same time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am creating an iOS application which needs to send and receive data at the same time while being in one viewController rather than a CentralView and a PeripheralView. Is this possible? I have been using apple's sample code for bluetooth but I can only get half the data I need from that. How can I send and receive data from bluetooth simultaneously while in one viewController?

Answer (score 1):

1. API is asynchronous so there is no problem
2. view controller should not do it. Write some class/service which will be manged by view controller, its life time should be different than view controller (depending on application).